# Scribble documentation --- PDF CREATION ERROR

Tags: pdf, racket, scribble

I am trying to generate a pdf file from scribble, but I got the following error message.

## Code

This is the simple toy example on which I am trying to generate the pdf.

```
#lang scribble/base
@title{Discourse}
@author{Racket}
```

## Error:

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14652 strings out of 478300
 207805 string characters out of 5849123
 474028 words of memory out of 5000000
 32574 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 495130 words of font info for 75 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,6n,77p,249b,334s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<c:/texlive/2022/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on documentation.pdf (1 page, 12585 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

run-pdflatex: got error exit code
  context...:
   D:\Racket\share\pkgs\scribble-lib\scribble\private\run-pdflatex.rkt:16:0: run
   D:\Racket\share\pkgs\scribble-lib\scribble\private\indirect-renderer.rkt:28:6
   D:\Racket\share\pkgs\scribble-lib\scribble\render.rkt:34:0: render
   D:\Racket\collects\racket\contract\private\arrow-val-first.rkt:555:3
   body of "D:\Racket\share\pkgs\scribble-lib\scribble\run.rkt"
```

Thanks in advance.